# Regular expression javascript to check comma separted numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

can somebody help me write a regex to use with test function for find exactly received number on list of string or numbers that has comma separated numbers.

For ex. I have number 125 like argument and string like '12,74,48,125,1253,1' or if it more easy to use list of numbers 12,74,48,125,1253,1 (I can use both)
How can I write regex to find exactly this number and return true o false.

I used this one, but it don't find if number has 3 o 4 digits

```
if(new RegExp('\\b'+number+'\\b').test('12,74,48,125,1253,1')){
alert('true');
}
```

This list can also be just only one number like '125'
I have little practice with regex.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many numbers will there be in a given set? Why not just use `split(",")` and check if the number is in the result? Or better yet, if you can give a list of numbers, just check if it is in the array?

Comment: Add , to the front and back of your string and search for ,<number>, where <number> is the number you're searching for

Answer (score 0):

> if it more easy to use list of numbers 12,74,48,125,1253,1

Don't use a regex. Just check to see if the number is in the array.

```
var nums = [12,74,48,125,1253,1];
if (nums.indexOf(125) >= 0) {
    alert('true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a regex, simply use `search` or `match` on the string, like

`var indexOfMatch = '12,74,48,125,1253,1'.search(/125/) // -1 if not present`

or

`var arrayOfMatches = '12,74,48,125,1253,1'.match(/125/) //returns an array of matches`

Then you can just test on the returned index (if its not -1) or the returned array (if it has length > 0) to determine if 125 is present.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [array indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method to solve your problem.

```
var list = '12,74,48,125,1253,1';

function isset(num) {
   return list.split(',').indexOf(""+num) === -1 ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return `... !== -1`?

Answer (score -1):

Why does it need to be a regex? If you are looking for an exact number, use indexOf:

```
var str = '12,74,48,125,1253,1';
var ix = str.indexOf('125');
if(ix == -1) /* number not found */;
```

Comment: @AndrewBarrett: True, he should also check if it is preceeded and succeeded by a comma, except at the start and the end of the string.